# Erlang - how to concatenate bit strings

Tags: erlang, bitstring

I'm trying to concatenate bit strings

```
 cowboy_req:reply(

               200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>},

               <<"<div style='color:#FF0'>">> ++ cowboy_req:host(Req) ++ <<"</div>">> , 

               Req
    )
```

but it gives runtime error because of `++` operator. How can I concatenate two bit strings?

Comment: Please take a look at the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963359/concatenating-bitstrings-not-binaries-in-erlang

Comment: I looked at that question but couldn't understand. There are some numbers like this `<<1,2>>` ,  but I have just strings in between `<< >>`

Comment: What about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/601482/1835621

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have here are normal binaries, not specifically bitstrings.

If you really want to concatenate them, store `cowboy_req:host(Req)` in a variable and then concatenate the 3 binaries:

```
Host = cowboy_req:host(Req),
cowboy_req:reply(
    200,
    #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>},
    <<"<div style='color:#FF0'>", Host/binary, "</div>">>, 
    Req
)
```

Note that since [`cowboy_req:reply`](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/1.0/manual/cowboy_req/#reply) accepts `iodata()`, it's usually more efficient to return a list like this:

```
cowboy_req:reply(
    200,
    #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>},
    [<<"<div style='color:#FF0'>">>, cowboy_req:host(Req), <<"</div>">>], 
    Req
)
```